# SSH communication - file sending from one device to another and vice versa

Tags: ssh, file-transfer

I want to be able to send a file via SSH **from device A to device B when using device A**, but also **from B to A when using device B**. Does it mean that both devices A and B must have installed SSH server and SSH client? Is there an easier way to achieve simple file sending between devices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research it turns out that both devices **do** must have installed SSH client and server. SSH itself does not provide any shortcut for that, but there are various libraries for various languages that can use both client and server (Apache SSHD, libssh...)

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this would be via the *nix "scp" utility. It uses SSH to transfer files. To transfer a file from host computer A to client computer B, computer B must be running an SSH server. I don't think you need to be running an SSH server on your local machine. So let's say you wanted to transfer the file /home/bob/document.txt from a remote laptop (B) on your home computer (A), and your remote laptop is running an SSH server, listening on the default port 22. Assume the remote laptop has an IP address of 188.188.188.188, and the username on the remote laptop is bob. Also assume that your local machine's username is bill. You would do

```
scp -P 22 bob@188.188.188.188:/home/bob/document.txt /home/bill/
```

Or, if you want to copy a document from your local machine to the remote, you'd do

```
scp -P 22 /home/bill/document.txt bob@188.188.188.188:/home/bob/
```

Technically, if the SSH server is left as the default on port 22, you don't need the "-P 22", but I included it so you can see what you'd do if you had it listening on a different port.

For more information, see [this](http://www.hypexr.org/linux_scp_help.php) super helpful scp syntax link.

Comment: Ah, I quess I didn't express myself clearly. When I want to be able to copy files from A to B when I use A, and from B to A when I use B.